# Primefaces p:dataTable with draggable&resizable&scrollable options

Tags: javascript, css, jsf, primefaces

Im trying to make primefaces p:dataTable work with this set of options.
Everything work fine when there is only draggable + resizable options activated. When scrollable is added then resizable option stop working properly and table looks like this:
[image: resizable columns crash]

I tryied to fix this by removing resizable option and add line
style="overflow: auto; height: 100%; width: 100%"
to my p:dataTable.

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="rec"
    value="#{someBean.table}"
    emptyMessage="#{dic.LBL1000no_records}"
    resizableColumns="true" 
    draggableColumns="true" 
    lazy="true"
    style="overflow: auto; height: 100%; width: 100%">
```

Effect is almost perfect, resizable worsk fine, I'm able to scroll table 
BUT THERE IS ONE MORE ISSUE: **I cant make horizontal scroll** :(
horizontal scroll became visible when I scroll table to the bottom, and the point is to able to use horizontal scroll all the time(because table have maany columns). I can't figure out how to deal with that problem. Help please!

Comment: THERE IS INDEED ONE MORE ISSUE... you forgot to post version info (and make an [mcve], so others cant explicitly try to reproduce)

Comment: @Kukeltje sorry for my my mistakes, as you can see I'm a very beginner. Here is github repo with compilable example: https://github.com/ntokarsk/PrimefacesTest.git